# Java applets in html

Tags: java, html, applet, object-tag

I can't seem to get this jar running in html when I am using the new object tag for HTML 5.
Do I need to add anything in order for this to work properly? This is how it look on the w3schools site, except they had it linked to a .swf file.

```html
<object height = "800" width="600" data="ECPrototype.jar"></object>
```

**UPDATE WITH CODE:**

```
import java.applet.Applet; 
import java.awt.Dimension;         
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class EC extends Applet implements ActionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Animation test= new Animation();
    Timer timer= new Timer(5,this);
    Thread thread = new Thread(test);
    Thread t = null; 
    public void init() {
    }
     public void stop() {
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        test.move();
        test.update();
        test.repaint();
    }

    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter implements ActionListener {

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            test.keyReleased(e);
            test.stopAnimation();
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            test.keyPressed(e);
            test.startAnimation();
            t= new Thread(test.animate);
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
    public EC()
    {
        thread.start();
        timer.start();
        JFrame window=new JFrame("EC");
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(test);
        window.addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        window.setFocusable(true);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new EC();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found [here](https://eyeasme.com/Shayne/HTML5_APPLETS/) and tested on my computer:

```html
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="400" height="400">
    <param name="code" value="name.of.your.Applet">
    <param name="archive" value="YourJarFile.jar">
</object>
```

---

About the frame issue, try rewriting constructor, init and main:

```
    public void init() {
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter()); // only executed in applet
    }
    public EC() {
        // executed in both applet and application
        thread.start();
        timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {   
        // only executed in application
        EC ec = new EC();
        JFrame window=new JFrame("EC");
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(ec.test);
        window.addKeyListener(ec.new TAdapter());
        window.setFocusable(true);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: still did not work, I tried using the example from the page you linked to and that didn't work either.  <object type="application/x-java-applet" width="800" height="600">
    <param name="code" value="ECPrototype">
    <param name="archive" value="ECPrototype.jar">
      Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.

</object>. That's what I have for mine.

Comment: @user1058860 Try to execute command `appletviewer path/to/your/document.html`. Is there any error message?

Comment: ok so I just did that grant permissions in the java.policy and it ran when I ran the command in the terminal, however it still did not work in safari.

Comment: also in firefox I get  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: I'm using jframe, should I be using something else? When I ran it in firefox it opened up a frame for the applet.

Comment: @user1058860 Can you provide your code? It's difficult to debug without code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    <applet code=TicTacToe.class 
    archive="ECPrototype.jar"
    width=120 height=120>
    </applet>
```

(The class has your main() I assume, the jar is the entire thing)